# how to use StackNavigation's navigate method in

Tags: android, react-native

I am creating an Android app, where the UI is done in react native.

The UI has 4 files:

1. `index.android.js`: automatically created with `react-native init <app_name>`
2. `Piper.js`: main entry to the app.
3. `Screen1.js`: screen #1 in the app.
4. `Screen2.js`: screen #2 in the app.

I'm using an Android-Nugat device (not emulator). Also running the project via the command line by `react-native run-android`

When clicking the button on `Screen1`(code bellow), I get the red screen:

[image]

**Question**

- Why the method `navigate`  (in `const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;`, see Screen1.js `render()` function) is undefined?
- How it should be used?
- What in the code that makes `StackNavigator` not to work?

**Here are the contents of the files:**

**`index.android.js`:**

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
const Piper = require('./js/Piper');
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Piper', () => Piper);
```

**Piper.js**

```
/**
 * @flow
 */
 import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
 const React = require('React');
 const Screen1 = require('./intro/Screen1');
 const Screen2 = require('./intro/Screen2');

 const piperRoute = StackNavigator({
    Screen1: { screen: Screen1},
    Screen2: { screen: Screen2},
  });

 class Piper extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
     super();
   }
   render(): React.Node {
     return (
       <Screen1 navigation={piperRoute}/>         
     );
   }
 }
module.exports = Piper;
```

**Screen1.js**

```
/**
 *
 * @providesModule Screen1
 * @flow
 */
"use strict";

import StackNavigator from 'react-navigation';
/* other imports used in render() */

class Screen1 extends React.Component<{navigation: StackNavigator}> {
  static navigationOptions = { title: "Welcome" }

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render(): React.Node {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          title='ok'          
          onPress={() => navigate('RequestPermission', {navigation: this.props.navigation})}
        />         
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({ /* ... styles ...*/});

module.exports = Screen1;
```

**Screen2.js**

```
/**
 *
 * @providesModule Screen2
 * @flow
 */
 'use strict';
 import StackNavigator from 'react-navigation';

 /* other imports */

 class Screen2 extends React.Component<{navigation: StackNavigator}> {
   render(): React.Node {
     return (
       <View>
         <Image ... />
       </View>
     );
   }
 }
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({ /* ... */ });
 module.exports = Screen2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead. You should pass the navigator for rendering in the entry point.Stack  navigator will auto load the screen1 component. The navigation prop will be available then only.

**Piper.js**

```
/**
 * @flow
 */
 import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
 const React = require('React');
 const Screen1 = require('./intro/Screen1');
 const Screen2 = require('./intro/Screen2');

 const piperRoute = StackNavigator({
    Screen1: { screen: Screen1},
    Screen2: { screen: Screen2},
  });

 class Piper extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
     super();
   }
   render(): React.Node {
     return (
       <piperRoute/>         
     );
   }
 }
module.exports = Piper;
```